Using Python to calculate pKa from titration curve for diprotic acid
The Issue
I would like to calculate the pKa of an acid from titration data. In order to do this, I would like to use nonlinear regression to fit the titration curve, so that I can use the equation of the curve to calculate the pKa. I am having difficulty figuring out which equation will fit this curve.
Attempt at a Solution
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import numpy as np

# The Data

x_list = [0.0,
 20.0,
 40.0,
 60.0,
 80.0,
 100.0,
 120.0,
 140.0,
 160.0,
 180.0,
 200.0,
 220.0,
 230.0,
 240.0,
 250.0,
 260.0,
 270.0,
 275.0,
 280.0,
 285.0,
 290.0,
 295.0,
 300.0,
 305.0,
 310.0,
 315.0,
 320.0,
 325.0,
 330.0,
 332.5,
 335.0,
 337.5,
 340.0,
 342.5,
 347.5,
 352.5,
 357.5,
 362.5,
 367.5,
 377.5,
 387.5,
 397.5,
 407.5,
 417.5,
 427.5,
 437.5,
 447.5,
 457.5,
 467.5,
 477.5,
 487.5,
 497.5,
 507.5,
 517.5,
 527.5,
 537.5,
 547.5,
 557.5,
 567.5,
 577.5,
 587.5,
 597.5,
 607.5,
 617.5,
 627.5,
 637.5,
 647.5,
 657.5,
 667.5,
 677.5,
 687.5,
 697.5,
 707.5,
 717.5,
 727.5,
 737.5,
 747.5,
 757.5,
 767.5,
 787.5,
 807.5,
 827.5,
 847.5,
 867.5]

y_list = [2.22,
 2.25,
 2.28,
 2.31,
 2.34,
 2.38,
 2.42,
 2.46,
 2.51,
 2.56,
 2.62,
 2.69,
 2.73,
 2.77,
 2.83,
 2.88,
 2.94,
 3.01,
 3.05,
 3.09,
 3.14,
 3.19,
 3.26,
 3.33,
 3.41,
 3.52,
 3.66,
 3.87,
 4.54,
 5.8,
 7.23,
 7.73,
 7.94,
 8.12,
 8.43,
 8.63,
 8.76,
 8.87,
 8.96,
 9.12,
 9.24,
 9.36,
 9.46,
 9.54,
 9.63,
 9.71,
 9.78,
 9.86,
 9.93,
 10.01,
 10.08,
 10.15,
 10.23,
 10.32,
 10.4,
 10.49,
 10.59,
 10.69,
 10.81,
 10.93,
 11.05,
 11.18,
 11.3,
 11.41,
 11.51,
 11.61,
 11.69,
 11.76,
 11.83,
 11.89,
 11.94,
 11.99,
 12.04,
 12.08,
 12.12,
 12.16,
 12.18,
 12.21,
 12.24,
 12.3,
 12.36,
 12.41,
 12.45,
 12.49]


fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=False, figsize=(15,4))

# smooth titration curve using Savitzky-Golay filter
x = np.array(x_list)
y = np.array(y_list)
y_smooth = scipy.signal.savgol_filter(y, window_length=3, polyorder=2, mode="nearest", deriv=0)

# Calculate first derivative curve
first_derivative_gradient = np.gradient(y_smooth, x)

# Plot titration curve and first derivative curve
titration = sns.lineplot(ax=axes[0], x=x, y=y_smooth, marker='.', markerfacecolor='black', markersize=10, color='black').set(title='Titration Curve', xlabel=r"Volume NaOH ($\mu$L)", ylabel='pH')
first_derivative = sns.lineplot(ax=axes[1], x=x, y=first_derivative_gradient, marker='.', markerfacecolor='black', markersize=10, color='black').set(title='1st Derivative', xlabel="Volume NaOH ($\mu$L)", ylabel="$\Delta$pH/$\Delta$V")



# display the plot

plt.show()


# Attempt to use Logistic Regression for curve fitting

def my_function_1(x, A, B, C, D, E):
    # this gives the best output
    return A/(1 + B**(x - C)) + D 

def my_function_2(x, A, B, C, D, E):
    return A/(1 + B**(x - C)) + D + E*x

def my_function_3(x, A, B, C, D, E):
    return C/(1 + (A*E)**(-B*x)) 

def run_regression(my_function, x, y_smooth):

    parameters, covariance = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f = my_function, xdata = x, ydata = y_smooth)

    for parameter, name in zip(parameters, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']):
        print(f'{name} = {parameter:14.10f}')

    x_fitted = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 1000)
    y_fitted = my_function(x_fitted, *parameters)
    
    return x_fitted, y_fitted

print('First Equation')
x_fitted_1, y_fitted_1 = run_regression(my_function_1, x, y_smooth)
print('\nSecond Equation')
x_fitted_2, y_fitted_2 = run_regression(my_function_2, x, y_smooth)
print('\nThird Equation')
x_fitted_3, y_fitted_3 = run_regression(my_function_3, x, y_smooth)



titration = sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y_smooth, marker='.', markerfacecolor='black', markersize=10, color='black').set(xlabel=r"Volume NaOH ($\mu$L)", ylabel='pH')
fitted_titration_curve_1 = sns.lineplot(x=x_fitted_1, y=y_fitted_1, marker='.', markerfacecolor='red', markersize=10, color='red')
fitted_titration_curve_2 = sns.lineplot(x=x_fitted_2, y=y_fitted_2, marker='.', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=10, color='blue')
fitted_titration_curve_3 = sns.lineplot(x=x_fitted_3, y=y_fitted_3, marker='.', markerfacecolor='green', markersize=10, color='green')

plt.show()

Script output - Titration curve and first derivative

Script Output - titration curve fitted to logistic regression


I tried three logistic regression formulas, none of which seem to work. The second equation I tried comes from How do I make a function from titration points in python?. I also looked at Unable to fit curves to data points using curve_fit() from scipy because of "Optimal parameters not found" error [python] but my curve does have have the same shape as the one in the example.

To clarify, is the issue that the curve does not fit the points very closely, or that you're not sure how to get from the coefficients found by curve_fit into a pKa value?

The issue is that the curve does not fit the points. I need a nonlinear regression that will fit the points.

I think I'll just use the Gran plot method to calculate the volume of base at the half-equivalence point, and then use linear regression to calculate the pKa from the flat, linear portion of the curve.

Ideally, you would like to add two "switch" curves (those that give a smooth transition between -1 and 1 over a range). The following gives a reasonable approximation to your data (although I'm suspicious that it's for the wrong reason).
It needs quite a good initial guess, I'm afraid.
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import numpy as np

x_list = [0.0, 
 20.0,
 40.0,
 60.0,
 80.0,
 100.0,
 120.0,
 140.0,
 160.0,
 180.0,
 200.0,
 220.0,
 230.0,
 240.0,
 250.0,
 260.0,
 270.0,
 275.0,
 280.0,
 285.0,
 290.0,
 295.0,
 300.0,
 305.0,
 310.0,
 315.0,
 320.0,
 325.0,
 330.0,
 332.5,
 335.0,
 337.5,
 340.0,
 342.5,
 347.5,
 352.5,
 357.5,
 362.5,
 367.5,
 377.5,
 387.5,
 397.5,
 407.5,
 417.5,
 427.5,
 437.5,
 447.5,
 457.5,
 467.5,
 477.5,
 487.5,
 497.5,
 507.5,
 517.5,
 527.5,
 537.5,
 547.5,
 557.5,
 567.5,
 577.5,
 587.5,
 597.5,
 607.5,
 617.5,
 627.5,
 637.5,
 647.5,
 657.5,
 667.5,
 677.5,
 687.5,
 697.5,
 707.5,
 717.5,
 727.5,
 737.5,
 747.5,
 757.5,
 767.5,
 787.5,
 807.5,
 827.5,
 847.5,
 867.5]

y_list = [2.22,
 2.25,
 2.28,
 2.31,
 2.34,
 2.38,
 2.42,
 2.46,
 2.51,
 2.56,
 2.62,
 2.69,
 2.73,
 2.77,
 2.83,
 2.88,
 2.94,
 3.01,
 3.05,
 3.09,
 3.14,
 3.19,
 3.26,
 3.33,
 3.41,
 3.52,
 3.66,
 3.87,
 4.54,
 5.8,
 7.23,
 7.73,
 7.94,
 8.12,
 8.43,
 8.63,
 8.76,
 8.87,
 8.96,
 9.12,
 9.24,
 9.36,
 9.46,
 9.54,
 9.63,
 9.71,
 9.78,
 9.86,
 9.93,
 10.01,
 10.08,
 10.15,
 10.23,
 10.32,
 10.4,
 10.49,
 10.59,
 10.69,
 10.81,
 10.93,
 11.05,
 11.18,
 11.3,
 11.41,
 11.51,
 11.61,
 11.69,
 11.76,
 11.83,
 11.89,
 11.94,
 11.99,
 12.04,
 12.08,
 12.12,
 12.16,
 12.18,
 12.21,
 12.24,
 12.3,
 12.36,
 12.41,
 12.45,
 12.49]


fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=False, figsize=(15,4))

# smooth titration curve using Savitzky-Golay filter
x = np.array(x_list)
y = np.array(y_list)
y_smooth = scipy.signal.savgol_filter(y, window_length=3, polyorder=2, mode="nearest", deriv=0)
first_derivative_gradient = np.gradient(y_smooth, x)

# Plot titration curve and first derivative curve
titration = sns.lineplot(ax=axes[0], x=x, y=y_smooth, marker='.', markerfacecolor='black', markersize=10, color='black').set(title='Titration Curve', xlabel=r"Volume NaOH ($\mu$L)", ylabel='pH')
first_derivative = sns.lineplot(ax=axes[1], x=x, y=first_derivative_gradient, marker='.', markerfacecolor='black', markersize=10, color='black').set(title='1st Derivative', xlabel="Volume NaOH ($\mu$L)", ylabel="$\Delta$pH/$\Delta$V")
plt.show()



# Different switch curves to try
def switch( x, B, C ):
    return ( x - C ) / ( B + abs(x - C) )
#   return np.arctan( B * ( x - C ) ) / ( np.pi / 2 )

def my_function(x, A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2, D, E ):
    return A1 * switch( x, B1, C1 ) + A2 * switch( x, B2, C2 ) + D + E * x

def run_regression(func, x, y_smooth):
    A1 = 2.75
    B1 = 0.3
    C1 = 333
    A2 = 0.01
    B2 = 0.1
    C2 = 450
    E = ( first_derivative_gradient[0] + first_derivative_gradient[-1] ) / 2
    D = 10

    p0 = [ A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2, D, E ]
    parameters, covariance = scipy.optimize.curve_fit( func, xdata=x, ydata=y_smooth, p0=p0 )

    x_fitted = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 1000)
    y_fitted = my_function(x_fitted, *parameters)
    print( "Parameters=", parameters )
    return x_fitted, y_fitted

x_fitted_1, y_fitted_1 = run_regression(my_function, x, y_smooth)

titration = sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y_smooth, marker='.', markerfacecolor='black', markersize=3, color='black').set(xlabel=r"Volume NaOH ($\mu$L)", ylabel='pH')
fitted_titration_curve_1 = sns.lineplot(x=x_fitted_1, y=y_fitted_1, marker='.', markerfacecolor='red', markersize=10, color='red')
plt.show()

Output:


Thank you, this is a pretty good approximation, I could try adjusting the parameters to improve the fit.

import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as opt
import seaborn as sns


x_list = [0.0,20.0,40.0,60.0,
 80.0,100.0,120.0,140.0,
 160.0,180.0,200.0,220.0,230.0,
 240.0,250.0,260.0,270.0,
 275.0,
 280.0,
 285.0,
 290.0,
 295.0,
 300.0,
 305.0,
 310.0,
 315.0,
 320.0,
 325.0,
 330.0,
 332.5,
 335.0,
 337.5,
 340.0,
 342.5,
 347.5,
 352.5,
 357.5,
 362.5,
 367.5,
 377.5,
 387.5,
 397.5,
 407.5,
 417.5,
 427.5,
 437.5,
 447.5,
 457.5,
 467.5,
 477.5,
 487.5,
 497.5,
 507.5,
 517.5,
 527.5,
 537.5,
 547.5,
 557.5,
 567.5,
 577.5,
 587.5,
 597.5,
 607.5,
 617.5,
 627.5,
 637.5,
 647.5,
 657.5,
 667.5,
 677.5,
 687.5,
 697.5,
 707.5,
 717.5,
 727.5,
 737.5,
 747.5,
 757.5,
 767.5,
 787.5,
 807.5,
 827.5,
 847.5,
 867.5]

y_list = [2.22,
 2.25,
 2.28,
 2.31,
 2.34,
 2.38,
 2.42,
 2.46,
 2.51,
 2.56,
 2.62,
 2.69,
 2.73,
 2.77,
 2.83,
 2.88,
 2.94,
 3.01,
 3.05,
 3.09,
 3.14,
 3.19,
 3.26,
 3.33,
 3.41,
 3.52,
 3.66,
 3.87,
 4.54,
 5.8,
 7.23,
 7.73,
 7.94,
 8.12,
 8.43,
 8.63,
 8.76,
 8.87,
 8.96,
 9.12,
 9.24,
 9.36,
 9.46,
 9.54,
 9.63,
 9.71,
 9.78,
 9.86,
 9.93,
 10.01,
 10.08,
 10.15,
 10.23,
 10.32,
 10.4,
 10.49,
 10.59,
 10.69,
 10.81,
 10.93,
 11.05,
 11.18,
 11.3,
 11.41,
 11.51,
 11.61,
 11.69,
 11.76,
 11.83,
 11.89,
 11.94,
 11.99,
 12.04,
 12.08,
 12.12,
 12.16,
 12.18,
 12.21,
 12.24,
 12.3,
 12.36,
 12.41,
 12.45,
 12.49]



# Convert to numpy arrays
x = np.array(x_list)
y = np.array(y_list)

# Smooth titration curve using Savitzky-Golay filter
y_smooth = scipy.signal.savgol_filter(y, window_length=5, polyorder=2)

# Logistic function for curve fitting
def logistic_function(x, A, K, B, C):
    z = -B * (x - C)
    z = np.clip(z, -500, 500)  # Prevent overflow
    return A + K / (1 + np.exp(z))
# Fit the curve
parameters, covariance = opt.curve_fit(logistic_function, x, y_smooth,
                         p0=[min(y_smooth), max(y_smooth) - min(y_smooth), 1, np.median(x)])

# Print fitted parameters
A, K, B, C = parameters
print(f'Fitted parameters:\nA = {A}\nK = {K}\nB = {B}\nC (approx. pKa) = {C}')

# Create fitted data for plotting
x_fitted = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
y_fitted = logistic_function(x_fitted, *parameters)

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y_smooth, label='Smoothed Titration Curve', marker='o', color='black')
sns.lineplot(x=x_fitted, y=y_fitted, label='Fitted Curve', color='red')
plt.title('Titration Curve with Fitted Logistic Function')
plt.xlabel('Volume NaOH (µL)')
plt.ylabel('pH')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
'''
Fitted parameters:
A = 2.3688955734951826
K = 8.818030086431211
B = 0.04360646247375154
C (approx. pKa) = 341.0811801713999

'''

<>
